# Need help understanding loops

Tags: c#

Ok what I am trying to do seems fairly simple, yet it's not working the way I want it. I know I'm just not getting something. Essentially I am trying to read console input, assign it to a variable. Then I want to check that variable to see if it is a valid number. If it's not, I want to tell the user it is invalid and start the loop over again until I get a valid number, then exit. Here is my code, can you please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
    const int AVERAGE_IQ = 100;
    int userIQ;
    bool done = false;

    do
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter an IQ Score between 1 and 200: ");
        userIQ = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (userIQ == 0 || userIQ >= 200)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid IQ Score, please try again.");
            done = false;
        }
        else if (userIQ >= AVERAGE_IQ)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is an above average IQ.", userIQ);
            done = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (userIQ <= AVERAGE_IQ)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is an below average IQ.", userIQ);
            done = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (userIQ == AVERAGE_IQ)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is anaverage IQ.", userIQ);
            done = true;
            break;
        }

    } while (done =! true);
```

Comment: This `while (done =! true);` should be `while (done != true);`

Comment: Can you tell me what this code is doing that you think is not the way it should be working? Also, since the check for being between 0 & 200 prevents the loop from terminating, there is no reason for the other if statements to be in the loop.

Comment: You'll also want to do some error checking on that call to `Convert.ToInt32`.  Maybe something like `int.TryParse` and if it fails display a useful error message and continue.

Comment: also, writing `mybool == true` is redundant. all you need here is `while(!done)`

Comment: Leave this question open please mods - I'll give him a serious answer...

Comment: Damn! Had a phone call, and in that time everyone has done the job for me...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`=!`  should be `!=`

You're doing an assignment, setting done to false.  Since:

`while (done =! true);`  is the same as  `while (done = !true);`  which is the same as `while (done = false);`

On each iteration, you're assigning done to be false, which itself evaluates to false, which means your loop will never iterate a second time.

Change the loop expression to either `while (done != true);`  or better yet `while (!done);`

Comment: I totally didn't catch that. This makes total sense why it wasn't looping.

Answer (score 6):

The error is in the last line:

```
while (done =! true);
```

What you are doing is assigning `done` `!true` which is `false` so regardless of the value of `done` before this statement executes, it will turn to `false` and the loop will exit.

What you really want is:

```
while (!done);
```

Also, as you are using `break` to break out of the loop, you can remove every line where `done` variable is used and just use this line without any problems:

```
while (true);
```

Answer (score 4):

while `done =! true` should be changed to while `done != true`

Answer (score 3):

As xanatos says. However, there is a style issue of your break vs. your done flag. The alternative to break, would be to keep the done flag - and remove the break statements. Your while would then become while (!done);

Comment: i was just about to say this. Also he can set done to true once at the beginning of the loop and remove the 3 `done = true` 's in the else if's

Comment: Ok so which is the "better" or "preferred" way to do this?

Comment: It depends... Do you think the egg was born before or after the chicken? :-) I always saw the break as a poor-man goto, so some persons can say it's bad... But it's probably clearer than changing the "done". So IN THIS EXAMPLE I would use the break. (the break has other problems... You can't "break x2" to exit two while loops one-in-another for example... And break means something else in switch/case statements.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check for `IQ < 0`
2. Change `>=` to `>`, `<=` to `<`
3. Delete all the `done` and change the `while` to `while (true)`

Comment: And if you want "perfect" use this: string str = Console.ReadLine();  if (!int.TryGetValue(str, out userIQ) || userIQ < 0 || userIQ >= 200) {

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

1. Change the `else if (userIQ >= AVERAGE_IQ)` to `else if (userIQ > AVERAGE_IQ)` Since you have the last "if they are equal"
2. Since you use `break;` to exit the loop, you do not need to set `done=true`

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "not working the way I want it"? Is it not prompting the user for input correctly? Is it displaying the incorrect message? Is it throwing an exception?

At first glance, I already see a bug. You check for >= AVERAGE_IQ then <= AVERAGE_IQ then == AVERAGE_IQ. If the user were to enter in the AVERAGE_IQ, the first condition would hit and it would say it's an above average IQ. The >= and <= should be > and < instead.

Also, the done flag is redundant since you're breaking. You might as well just use a while (true) loop if you're going to use breaks.

Another thing, you aren't handling negative input correctly. It should also display that out of range error message.

Edit: as many other have pointed out, "=!" is not the same thing as "!=".

Answer (score 0):

The loop is there to deal with getting the user to enter the correct input.  Evaluating that input beyond being in the appropriate range should be moved somewhere else.

If you restructure your code to something like this, it is more clear what you are trying to do.

```
int minIQ = 1;
int maxIQ = 200;
do
{
    Console.Write("Please enter an IQ Score between " + minIQ + " and " + maxIQ + ": ");
    userIQ = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
} while (userIQ >= minIQ && userIQ <= maxIQ);

//Test userIQ and output here.
```

Comment: wouldn't doing `while (userIQ >= minIQ && userIQ <= maxIQ)` and removing the if statement be easier?